# Is code within DispatchQueue.global.async executed serially?

Tags: swift, macos, grand-central-dispatch

I have some code that looks like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    self.fetchProjects()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.constructMenu()
    }
}
```

My question is are the blocks within the global block executed serially? When I add print statements, they always executed in the same order, but I'm not sure if I'm getting lucky as looking at the documentation, it says:

> Tasks submitted to the returned queue are scheduled concurrently with respect to one another.

I wonder if anyone can shed any light on this?

EDIT:

Apologies, I don't think I made the question clear. I would like for the method `constructMenu` to only be called once `fetchProjects` has completed. From what I can tell (by logging print statements) this is the case.

But I'm not really sure *why* that's the case if what Apple's documentation above says (where each task is scheduled concurrently) is true.

Is code within an async block always executed serially, or is the fact that the code seems to execute serially a result of using `DispatchQueue.main` or is it just 'luck' and at some point `constructMenu` will actually return *before* `fetchProjects`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like for the method `constructMenu` to only be called once `fetchProjects` has completed. From what I can tell (by logging print statements) this is the case.

Yes, this is the case.

> But I'm not really sure why that's the case if what Apple's documentation above says (where each task is scheduled concurrently) is true.

Apple’s documentation is saying that two separate dispatches may run concurrently with respect to each other.

Consider:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    foo()
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    bar()
}
```

In this case, `foo` and `bar` may end up running at the same time. This is what Apple means by “Tasks submitted to the returned queue are scheduled concurrently.”

But consider:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    foo()
    bar()
}
```

In this case, `bar` will not run until we return from `foo`.

> Is code within an async block always executed serially, or is the fact that the code seems to execute serially a result of using `DispatchQueue.main` or is it just ‘luck’ and at some point `constructMenu` will actually return before `fetchProjects`?

No luck involved. It will never reach the `DispatchQueue.main.async` line until you return from `fetchProjects`.

There is one fairly major caveat, though. This assumes that `fetchProjects` won’t return until the fetch is done. That means that `fetchProjects` better not be initiating any asynchronous processes of its own (i.e. no network requests). If it does, you probably want to supply it with a completion handler, and put the call to `constructMenu` in that completion handler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, blocks of code are submitted as blocks, and those blocks run sequentially. So for your example:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    self.fetchProjects()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.constructMenu()
    }
}
```

`fetchProjects()` must complete before `constructMenu` is enqueued. There is no magic here. The block between `{...}` is submitted as a block. At some point in the future it will executed. But the pieces of the block will not be considered in any granular way. They will start at the top, `fetchProjects`, and then the next line of code will be executed, `DispatchQueue.main.async`, which accepts as a parameter another block. The complier doesn't know anything about these blocks. It just passes them to functions, and those functions put them on queues.

Comment: This seems to imply that the answer to the OP's question ("Is code within DispatchQueue.global.async executed serially?") is yes. It isn't. It's no. It's a concurrent queue, not a serial queue. For example, it would be possible for lines of code within `fetchProducts` to be executed multiple times interleaved with one another. That is in distinction to `main` which is serial and can only be executing one sequence of code at a time. It is absolutely not true that "fetchProjects, and then the next line of code will be executed, DispatchQueue.main.async". Other things could happen in between.

Comment: @matt The cod within the `async` block *is* executed serially. I agree that it's possible for lots of other things to happen, but it's not possible for the `.async` call to be made before `fetchProducts` completes. That piece of code is serial. "Serial" does not mean "atomic," and I don't think I've suggested it does.

Comment: Specifically, the question "I would like for the method constructMenu to only be called once fetchProjects has completed. From what I can tell (by logging print statements) this is the case." That is absolutely promised for this block of code. (Obviously *other* blocks of code could introduce a different call to `constructMenu`, but *this* block of code promises what is asked.)

Answer (score 0):

`DispatchQueue.global` is a concurrent queue that mean all tasks submitted run asynchronously at the same time , if you need it serially create a custom queue

```
let serial = DispatchQueue(label: "com.queueName")
serial.sync {
    ///
}
```

Comment: I know this is correct but it would help to confirm this with a link to some documentation or a header file or something. I can't find anything from Apple that states this fact.

Comment: @rmaddy actually don't have , know with trial and error , if you find a doc you can edit the answer

Comment: Well this is what I don’t understand since RayWenderlich says that “ Targeting the main queue and calling async guarantees that this new task will execute sometime after the current method finishes.”

Comment: @HenryCooper - That’s a completely different issue than your original question, “are global queues concurrent” (which they are). The author of this quote here is saying that if you have method running on the main queue which then dispatches something else asynchronously back to the main queue, that dispatched code will not run until you leave the current method (which is also true). But that’s because the main queue is a serial queue. Your original question was about global (concurrent) queues, so I’m unclear why you’re introducing quote about main (serial) queue.

Comment: @Rob thanks Rob, I have updated the question to make it (I think) more clear

Comment: @HenryCooper "RayWenderlich says that “ Targeting the main queue and calling async guarantees that this new task will execute sometime after the current method finishes" - Yes, the _main_ queue. But that is not what you asked about. You asked about the DispatchQueue.global. That is a different queue and it behaves completely differently.